# Install Python for Windows

Tags: windows, python, installer

What is the best way to install Python for Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download the executable ("Windows Installer") from [python.org](http://python.org/download/) and install it.

Answer (score 2):

For an IDE based full package install for Scientific computing I have used [Python-x,y](http://www.pythonxy.com/foreword.php) and it comes with the kitchen sink.

Answer (score 2):

[Active Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/)

> ActivePython is the industry-standard Python distribution, available for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, AIX and HP-UX.

Comment: Active Python is a CPython package

Comment: You comment that "Active Python is a CPython package"  <-- can you elaborate on the relevance of that? particularly as the OP's question is a newbie type question so many people reading this QnA might not know the implications of whatever that is, are..

Comment: @barlop - 6 years after posting and question moved to another site, I agree that the comment is irrelevant to a newbie.

Comment: -1 the standard cpython distribution for windows or linux, is from python.org, not ActivePython.

Comment: And I think you are wrong again to use the term cpython package, Python has packages you can import in, but CPython is not a package it is an implementation. (And AFAIK packages aren't really dependent on implementation, they are code). And ActivePython is a distribution not  a package.

Comment: You are misleading saying 6 years. It is not that your answer has gone out of date since after you posted it 6 years ago. A python distribution was available from python.org even in 2001 (and yeah, cpython implementation, as they do)  web.archive.org/web/20020602032836/python.org/ftp… And more importantly, I think maybe that quote that you have about ActivePython is marketing. Most people on windows either use Python for windows, that is available on python.org or perhaps if they're scientists, apparently these two are quite good, enthought canopy, anaconda

Comment: And the Python releases on python.org are so standard they aren't even considered distributions. And you quoted from a page where just aboev the line you quoted from, it says "World's best python distribution" so you should've known it was just marketting. Very misleading.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://blog.sadphaeton.com/2009/01/20/python-development-windows-part-1installing-python.html) is the best install guide I've ever seen. Don't forget [Part 2](http://blog.sadphaeton.com/2009/01/20/python-development-windows-part-2-installing-easyinstallcould-be-easier.html) to get `easy_install` working, as well.

Answer (score 1):

In this article, I will explain how to install Python using the steps mentioned above. First of all, I want to say that Python is an open source project, which means that it is available to everyone for anyone to use and modify. For that reason, there are many tutorials on the web, which can help you install Python using the steps mentioned below.

To start off, first of all, get the program called Python Installer. To install python, all you need to do is run an executable file named install python (wherever you obtained the program) and it will install the necessary modules and files needed by your Python interpreter to run properly. But be sure you download the most recent release of the Python interpreter, because the older ones can break your computer., but don't worry - this is very rare. Usually, the standard library for Python is included in the program when you install it. If not, you can search online for an updated list of the available standard library for your operating system. need to be in a directory that contains Python installation files, such as C:/ python. Once you've found the right place to store the files, run the following command to install the required modules:

In order to successfully install Python on Windows, you first need to be able to run Python from your command line prompt. To start Python, you need to open up a command line window. To do that, click Start, then Run, on the menu at the left of the screen. When the command line prompt appears, type "pip." It's likely that you'll be prompted to key in your user name and password, so be sure to always remember those!

Finally, if you don't have a recent version of Python installed, you also have two options. You can download and install the latest official release of Python, or you can use a homebrew package manager to install Python. Although the installation process is typically straightforward, it can get a bit complicated if you're not familiar with working with programs like Homebrew. If you're running into problems, or if you aren't comfortable working with the command line at all, it may be easiest just to use a homebrew package manager to get Python running on your computer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! There are other answers (and a accepted one) that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer (see: [answer]), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a as short as possible and substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center.

Answer (score 0):

Get [**ActivePython**](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/) for Windows.

See [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/installnotes.html#install_win) for installation instructions.

In addition to the installer at python.org, ActivePython includes pywin32 (Windows API extensions) and several unofficial documentation including tutorials to learn Python.

Answer (score 0):

Download Python.exe from the Python website. Then, install IDLE or PyCharm or any other Python editing software and set the interpreter as your Python.exe file. You should be set.